# ReactJS.Net where to start ASP services?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs

I'm working on a new project, we're migrating all frontend from jQuery to React and we use ASP.Net as back-end. The previous project is an `ASP.Net Web Application`, we run the server from `index.aspx` and access it's methods with ajax from jQuery. That's ok, but now we're using the ReacJS.Net template, which is kind of different, I'm not an ASP.net expert and don't really know where to start.

The tree folder looks like this:

```
>bin
  >Debug
>ClientApp
  >components
  >css
  boot.js
>Controllers
>node_modules
>obj
  >Debug
    >netcoreapp2.0
      LPMU.Web.AssemblyInfo.cs
      LPMU.Web.AssemblyInfoInfoInput.cache
      LPMU.Web.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
      LPMU.Web.dll
      LPMU.Web.pdb
  LPMU.Web.csproj.nuget.cache
  LPMU.Web.csproj.nuget.g.props
  LPMU.Web.csproj.nuget.g.targets
  project.assets.json
>package
  >services
    >metadata
      >coreproperties
>Properties
  launchSettings.json
    >Views

>wwwroot
[Content_Types].xml
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.json
LICENSE
LPMU.Web.csproj
LPMU.Web.csproj.user
npm-shrinkwrap.json
package.json
Program.cs
README.md
Startup.cs
webpack.config.js
webpack.config.vendor.js
yarn-error.log
yarn.lock
```

I think Program.cs or Startup.cs would be the place to start it, but I'm not sure and don't know where to find some docummentation about this. If somebody could help I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say in the StartUp.cs, because a lot of configuration happens there. For example: when you create a new project and check the project structure, you will see that all the configuration for SPA and other stuff is put in there.

Another thing that is configured there is the webpack. I would suggest to take a look at that, aswell as the webpack.config.